# Java sort int[] base on another int[]

Tags: java

Suppose I want an array that has the index of the sorted xCoordinates: 
sample input : [20, 10, 30, 40, 50]
sample output : [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]

I tried:

```
public int[] findSortedIndex(int[] arr) {
    int[] sortedIndex = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sortedIndex[i] = i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(sortedIndex, (a, b) -> arr[a] - arr[b]);
    return sortedIndex;
}
```

But this gives me an error ("`no suitable method found for sort(int[],(a,b)->arr[...]rr[b])`"). Any clean way to do this?

Comment: "this gives me an error" - what error?

Comment: @Progman The code provided is a [mcve].

Comment: Unclear whether the array containing the sorted indexes is the input or output.

Comment: @RetoHöhener I think it's quite clear that it is the output since it's being returned.

Comment: @iota Title says 'based on another int[]', indicating input.

Comment: @RetoHöhener The asker wants to sort the array of indexes based on the original array. No other input is required.

Comment: @iota Probably, but the title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `Integer` array instead since `Arrays.sort` only accepts a `Comparator` as a second argument for `Object` arrays.

```
public Integer[] findSortedIndex(int[] arr) {
    Integer[] sortedIndex = new Integer[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sortedIndex[i] = i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(sortedIndex, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> arr[a]));
    return sortedIndex;
}
```

You can convert the `Integer` array to an `int` array at the end of the method as well.

```
public int[] findSortedIndex(int[] arr) {
    Integer[] sortedIndex = new Integer[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sortedIndex[i] = i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(sortedIndex, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> arr[a]));
    return Arrays.stream(sortedIndex).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do what you need is to encapsulate your values and indexes in various objects, sort them and retrieve only the indexes.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {

    private static class ValueAndIndex {
        
        private int v;
        private int i;
        
        ValueAndIndex( int v, int i ) {
            this.v = v;
            this.i = i;
        }
        
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( 
                findSortedIndex( new int[]{ 20, 10, 30, 40, 50 } ) ) );
    }

    public static int[] findSortedIndex( int[] arr ) {
        
        ValueAndIndex[] valuesAndIndexes = new ValueAndIndex[arr.length];
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
            valuesAndIndexes[i] = new ValueAndIndex( arr[i], i );
        }
        
        Arrays.sort( valuesAndIndexes, ( a, b ) -> a.v - b.v );
        return Arrays.stream( valuesAndIndexes ).mapToInt( v -> v.i ).toArray();
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
private static int[] findSortedIndex(int[] ints) {
    return IntStream.range(0, ints.length)
            .boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> ints[i]))
            .mapToInt(i -> i)
            .toArray();
}
```

The `sorted` method on `IntStream` does not take a `Comparator` as argument, so we need to box and unbox the ints, adding two extra steps.